# Custom Bar with Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to draw a bar like this:

```
\documentclass[convert = false, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    
    \newcommand{\dist}{0.025\linewidth}

    \newcommand{\swr}[5]{% 1:x1 2:y1 3:x2 4:y2 5:percent
        \pgfmathsetmacro \val {#1+#5*(#3-#1)};
        \fill[gray] (#1,#2) rectangle (\val,#4);
        \draw[very thick] (#1,#2) rectangle (#3,#4);
        \foreach \i in {1,...,4} {
            \pgfmathsetmacro \x {#1+(\i-1)*(#3-#1)/3};
            \node at (\x,#2-\dist) {\ifthenelse{\i=4}{$\infty$}{\i}};
        }
    }

    \swr{1}{0}{5}{1}{0.5};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: Expected]

However if I use relative placement w.r.t. linwidth, everything breaks:

```
\swr{0.1\linewidth}{0.55\linewidth}{0.5\linewidth}{0.55\linewidth+\dist}{0.5};
```

[image]

Any Ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: The default unit in `\pgfmathsetmacro` is pt.  Maybe it helps.

Comment: Seems that using ```\pgfmathsetlengthmacro``` does the job then

Comment: The \linewidth is 345.0pt, the value of \val is 103..50105 it's the problem?

Comment: With "\pgfmathsetmacro \val {(#1+#5*(#3-#1))/28.346};" the approximative conversion in cm it's better.  Add \pgfplotsset{compat=1.18} in the preamble

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image: examples]

I modified your command trying to homogenize the arguments.

- The name is `\mswr`.
- It has one optional argument (the first) that determines the scaling of the other 5 arguments.  If it is empty, the scaling is 1.  I think it is easier to use it this way.
- I changed the arguments 3 and 4 in your definition by connecting them to the arguments 1 and 2 respectively.  It allowed me to get rid of the variable `\dist` in your definition.

**Remark** I cannot really figure out the context in which you would like to use your command.  Will it be a part of a larger figure, or will it be used by itself among text paragraphs?  In the former case, the definition might be improved, I think...  For example not having the first two compulsory arguments, and, probably a question of taste, to have it as a `pic` element and not as a `\newcommand`.

**The code**

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article} % [convert = false, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}  % pgfplots
\usetikzlibrary{math}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

    
\newcommand{\dist}{0.025\linewidth}
\newcommand{\swr}[5]{% 1:x1 2:y1 3:x2 4:y2 5:percent
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\val}{#1+#5*(#3-#1)};
  \fill[gray] (#1,#2) rectangle (\val,#4);
  \draw[very thick] (#1,#2) rectangle (#3,#4);
  \foreach \i in {1,...,4} {
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\x}{#1+(\i-1)*(#3-#1)/3};
    \node at (\x,#2-\dist) {\ifthenelse{\i=4}{$\infty$}{\i}};
  }
}

\newcommand{\mswr}[7][]{%
  % 1:thales (1 if empty) 2:x1 3:y1 4:x2-x1 5:y2-y1 6:percent
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{}}{\tikzmath{\c = 1cm/1pt;}}{\tikzmath{\c = #1;}}
  \tikzmath{%
    integer \i;
    {%
      \fill[blue!40] (#2*\c pt, #3*\c pt) rectangle ++(#6*#4*\c pt, #5*\c pt);
      \draw[blue, very thick] (#2*\c pt, #3*\c pt) rectangle ++(#4*\c pt, #5*\c pt);
    };
    for \i in {1, ..., 4}{%
      \x = #2*\c +(\i -1)*#4*\c/3;
      if \i<4 then {%
        {%
          \path (\x pt, #3*\c pt) node[below, minimum height=3.1ex] {$\i$};
        };
      } else {%
        {%
          \path (\x pt, #3*\c pt) node[below, minimum height=3.1ex] {$\infty$};
        };        
      };
    };
  }
}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\section*{The modified command is in blue}

There is no difference if the arguments are numbers.

\bigskip
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \swr{1}{0}{5}{1}{0.5};
  \mswr{1}{-2}{4}{1}{0.5};  
\end{tikzpicture}


Below, the arguments are relative quantities with respect to \verb|\linewidth|.

\bigskip
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (0, 0) grid (7, 4);
  \filldraw (7, 0) circle (2pt) node[below right] {$(7, 0)$};

  \swr{0.1\linewidth}{0.05\linewidth}{0.5\linewidth}{0.05\linewidth+\dist}{0.5};
  \mswr[\linewidth]{.1}{.2}{.4}{.025}{.5};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Nice solution. Remark: the package pgfplots is not needed, and it causes a latex warning.

Comment: Thanks twice @pascal974 !